# Can not Load CAD model to Visualization Convas

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

It does not want to load cad model into visualization convas, I flow CAD Models Tutorial in KnowRob Wiki

---

Terminal inside mod_vis

```
?- register_ros_package(knowrob_cad_models).
%  library(knowrob_cad_models) compiled into knowrob_cad_models 0.00 sec, 2,632 bytes
% /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_cad_models/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 4,912 bytes
true.

?- owl_has(A, rdf:type, knowrob:'DrinkingBottle'), add_object(A, $C).
false.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49024/can-not-load-cad-model-to-visualization-convas/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You need to start the visualization canvas.
2. Are you sure you have an instance of DrinkingBottle in your knowledge base?

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-26**:
I do, but thanks I will try again after have more deeper understanding,

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-01-03**:
After load ias_semantic_map, I can run owl_has(A, rdf:type, knowrob:'Drawer'), add_object(A, $C).